# EXC_BAD_ACCESS Exception (Segmentation Fault) when editing 2D Dynamic Array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation, dynamic-arrays

I'm creating a program that counts the number of occurrences of each inputted character and stores them in a dynamically allocated 2d array by their ASCII value.

When a new character is found, the array increases by one row and the new character is added to the table

if it is an existing character, the counter for the character is increased by 1.

However, when adding a 4th unique character no matter the order of insertion an EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception occurs. When following the trail of the array from the exception, it either leads to a value or returns unable to access memory.

I've tested this over multiple IDEs and still same error.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <ctype.h>

#include <assert.h>

void unique_character_counter (int** unique_character_table, char character);
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    /* initialisation of character counting table */
    int **unique_character_table = malloc(sizeof(int*)*1);
    unique_character_table[0] = malloc(sizeof(int)*2);

    unique_character_counter(unique_character_table, 'a');
    unique_character_counter(unique_character_table, 'b');
    unique_character_counter(unique_character_table, 'b');
    unique_character_counter(unique_character_table, 'b');
    unique_character_counter(unique_character_table, 'b');
    unique_character_counter(unique_character_table, 'c');
    unique_character_counter(unique_character_table, 'd');
    unique_character_counter(unique_character_table, 'e');


}

void unique_character_counter (int** unique_character_table, char character){
    /* static variable that counts number of rows */
    static int unique_characters = 0;
    int is_unique_character = 1;

    printf("\n Current Char: %c\n", character);

    /* initialising value of first character to be entered*/
    if (unique_characters ==0){
        unique_character_table[0][0]=(int)character;
        unique_character_table[0][1]=1;
        unique_characters++;

    }

    else{
        /* cycle through array to see if character matches any existing character */
        for(int counter_cycler = 0; counter_cycler < unique_characters; counter_cycler ++){
            if (unique_character_table[counter_cycler][0]== (int)character){
                /* if character already exists, increase its count by 1 */
                is_unique_character = 0;
                unique_character_table[counter_cycler][1]++;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (is_unique_character == 1){
            /* If character is unique, increase rows by 1 allocate memory of knew columns, add char ascii value to first column and counter to second */
            unique_characters ++;
            unique_character_table = realloc(unique_character_table, sizeof(int*)*unique_characters);
            unique_character_table[unique_characters-1] = malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
            unique_character_table[unique_characters-1][0]=(int)character;
            unique_character_table[unique_characters-1][1]=1;

        }

    }
    /* Printing array table */
    printf(" unique char: %d\n", unique_characters);
    for(int print_cycler = 0; print_cycler < unique_characters; print_cycler ++){
        for(int x = 0; x < 2; x ++){
            printf("%d-", unique_character_table[print_cycler][x] );
        }
        printf("\n");

    }
}
```

The desired final output should be a table like this
97-1,
98-4,
99-1,
100-1,
101-1

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Remember that arguments in C are passed *by value*. That means the value used in the call is *copied* into the functions local argument variable. Any changes to the functions local argument variable (like assigning to it) will only happen to that variable. I recommend you either *return* the new `unique_character_table`, or research *emulating pass by reference in C*.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your code is, at some point, dereferencing a unspecified value.

Why dynamically allocate the array? It's way more expensive that way, since there's only 256 values, just allocating an array of 256 integers is going to be a lot less wasteful, keep in mind there's substantial overhead added by the allocator to keep track of the memory, and also your code is very convoluted.

If you were to keep the dynamic allocation, at least delegate that into a secondary function, **and check the return value of every call to malloc/realloc**. However a statically allocated table is much simpler, your code would translate to:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void print_array_table(unsigned int *tbl)
{
    unsigned left = tbl[256];
    printf("unique chars: %u\n", left);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 256 && left; i++, left--) {
        /* skip empty */
        if (!tbl[i]) {
            while (!tbl[i] && i < 256) i++;
            if (i == 256) break;
        }
        printf("%u-%u\n", i, tbl[i]);
    }
}

static void count_char(unsigned int *tbl, char val)
{
    if (!tbl[val]++) tbl[256]++;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned int *uniq_tbl;
    uniq_tbl = calloc(257, sizeof(*uniq_tbl));
    if (!uniq_tbl) {
        fputs("Out of memory!\n", stderr);
        abort();
    }
    
    count_char(uniq_tbl, 'a');
    count_char(uniq_tbl, 'b');
    count_char(uniq_tbl, 'b');
    count_char(uniq_tbl, 'b');
    count_char(uniq_tbl, 'b');
    count_char(uniq_tbl, 'c');
    count_char(uniq_tbl, 'd');
    count_char(uniq_tbl, 'e');
    print_array_table(uniq_tbl);
    return 0;
}
```